# Wordpress enqueue a script with dynamic name

Tags: php, wordpress, reactjs

I have been studying React and have succesfully implemented into a wordpress website. The issue i face is everytime i create a build version of the app, it changes my js and css files that need to be enqueued in functionns.php

I am trying to find a way to have php select ANY .js or .css in the pointed directories, so that i do not have to manually change the name of the script every time i create a new build of the applet.

I have tried to extract the filename using scandir(directory) so it would return the files, and then I could select the .js or .css file accordingly. Then input that variable into my enqueue. This is the code i tried, and below it the error im getting.

```
if (is_page("BOLETIN Y REVISTA")){
        $cssFile = scandir(get_template_directory_uri() .'/cipm-ebooks-react/build/static/css/');
        print_r($cssFile);
        wp_enqueue_style('react-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/cipm-ebooks-react/build/static/css/main.5660ef71.css', array(), '2', false);
        wp_enqueue_script( 'react-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/cipm-ebooks-react/build/static/js/main.a405b746.js', array(), '2', true );
    }
```

The error I get constantly: 
Warning: scandir(https://cipm.org.mx/wp-content/themes/cipm-dev/cipm-ebooks-react/build/static/css/): failed to open dir: not implemented in /Users/juandelgado/Sites/cipm.org.mx/wp-content/themes/cipm-dev/functions.php on line 38

Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in /Users/juandelgado/Sites/cipm.org.mx/wp-content/themes/cipm-dev/functions.php on line 38

any help is super welcome thanks!

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/276897/130535 this might be waht you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using glob and basename. I'm sure there are other ways to get it to work, but glob() was tricky because it returned an entire path string. To ge the actual name of the script I did the following, and it works wonderfully

```
if (is_page("BOLETIN Y REVISTA")){

        $cssPath = glob('wp-content/themes/cipm-dev/cipm-ebooks-react/build/static/css/*.css');
        $cssFile = basename($cssPath[0]);
        $jsPath = glob('wp-content/themes/cipm-dev/cipm-ebooks-react/build/static/js/*.js');
        $jsFile = basename($jsPath[0]);

        wp_enqueue_style('react-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/cipm-ebooks-react/build/static/css/'.$cssFile, array(), '2', false);
        wp_enqueue_script( 'react-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/cipm-ebooks-react/build/static/js/'.$jsFile, array(), '2', true );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
 if(is_page("BOLETIN Y REVISTA")){

        foreach( glob( get_template_directory_uri() . '/cipm-ebooks-react/build/static/js/*.js' ) as $file ) {
            // $file contains the name and extension of the file
            wp_enqueue_script( $file, get_template_directory_uri() . '/cipm-ebooks-react/build/static/js/'. $file);
        }

        foreach( glob(get_template_directory_uri() . '/cipm-ebooks-react/build/static/css/*.css' ) as $file ) {
            // $file contains the name and extension of the file
            wp_enqueue_style( $file, get_template_directory_uri() . '/cipm-ebooks-react/build/static/css/'. $file);
        }

    }
```